# Not able to load local csv data into Highcharts

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Highchart from data stored in local csv file, but I'm just getting a "blank" chart in html. Csv file is in same place as html file.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Highcharts</title>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/modules/data.js"></script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/themes/gray.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></div>
  </body>

   <script>    
   $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
        data: {
        // enablePolling: true,
            csvURL: window.location.origin + 'test.csv',
            itemDelimiter: ';',
            lineDelimiter: '\n',
    },   
        title: {
            text: 'Fuel Consumption'
        },
    });
}); 
    </script>
</html>
```

This is the content of my csv file:

```
DateTime;Value
09/06/2018 18:00:15;1296.26098632813
09/06/2018 18:28:09;1451.98901367188
09/06/2018 18:56:03;563.752014160156
09/06/2018 19:23:57;429.237213134766
09/06/2018 19:51:51;445.504516601563
09/06/2018 20:19:45;1216.92199707031
09/06/2018 20:47:39;1108.98400878906
09/06/2018 21:15:34;478.514709472656
09/06/2018 21:43:28;649.652221679688
09/06/2018 22:11:22;159.626998901367
09/06/2018 22:39:16;135.208999633789
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think you forgot the `/` in `window.location.origin + '/test.csv'`

Comment: No, it is not that @Core972

Comment: So what does the console say?

Comment: @Halvor. It's working now. Had to put the whole "app" in a node.js web server. The console did not output anything. Now on to getting the range selector working...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this demo is that the file path isn't correct.
If you log the window location you are using, you'll see it's null. Try:

```
console.log(window.location.origin)
```

It was discussed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409505/file-loading-a-csv-file-into-highcharts).

Try putting your CSV on your (a) server and then use the fully qualified path name. For example:

```
csvURL:'https://myserver/data/test.csv'
```